# How to run mongo db queries from IDEA using an external file?

Tags: javascript, sql, mongodb, intellij-idea, mongodb-query

I'm trying to run mongodb queries in IntelliJ IDE using some external file. Found [this source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sql-for-mongodb.html) but it didn't help.

One way they mention is using a select. I created a file, named my_collection.sql and assigned it the mongodb source. It worked but I'm stuck on the where, for example the following works:

```
select * from my_collection;
```

But when trying to add a where clause, the following query returns an empty result:

```
select * from my_collection
where
_id = "63fe1bee9acb9d2d0f175578";
```

Another way I'm trying to run is using the js api, for example, using the console, so this works:

```
db.getSiblingDB("my_db").getCollection("my_collection")
.find({_id: new ObjectId("63fe1a039acb9d76017ee780")})
.limit(21)
```

Buy, I'm unable to save the query to a file so it can be re-run.

Is there some way to assign some js file to be run on a mongodb connection?

Comment: Export data to a file can be achieved via Data Extractor:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/export-data.html#methods-for-exporting-data

As for the empty output, I'd suggest opening a support issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: @AlexanderMolchanov, thanks but it's not the output export that i'm interested in - it's the input, specifically putting the input query in a separate file, so I can back it up, for example.

Comment: You can retrieve the query history from Browse Query History: 

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/run-a-query.html#use_the_query_history_dialog